# How to change snowflake async query timeout in snowflake?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I run an async query via snowflake python connector I get a result indicating the query will be aborted if it takes more than 300 seconds.

```py
cursor_result = sf_conn.cursor().execute_async(
                  "select 1 as test_column", timeout=500)
```

```py
'queryId':'01a00000-0404-bce3-0000-00013778eb6f'
'getResultUrl':'/queries/01a54712-0404-bce3-00c6-55013778eb6f/result'
'queryAbortsAfterSecs':300
'progressDesc':None
```

Passing `timeout` param doesn't seem to be helping and the value is still 300 seconds!

I want to know how to change this default behavior and to change the default value of 300 seconds?

Comment: so far the only thing I found for this is the warehouse `timeout` value is being enforced on queries and not the timeout we are passing here, nor the `queryAbortsAfterSecs` having any effect on the query lifetime!

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the code here https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/efeaeb15bdae7b7378b8a007bb9fe22e7f540669/src/snowflake/connector/cursor.py#L468-L470, it looks like network timeout plays a role in deciding the query timeout.

```
    real_timeout = (
        timeout if timeout and timeout > 0 else self._connection.network_timeout
    )

    if real_timeout is not None:
        self._timebomb = Timer(real_timeout, self.__cancel_query, [query])
        self._timebomb.start()
        logger.debug("started timebomb in %ss", real_timeout)
    else:
        self._timebomb = None
```

What's your network connection timeout set to?

Comment: when providing timeout as the parameter this will not take `network_timeout`, instead it will use the passed value, but the problem is I see another value in the response, I'm not sure the 300 value in the response have anything to do with this timeout!

Comment: also, the network timeout is infinite by default https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/efeaeb15bdae7b7378b8a007bb9fe22e7f540669/src/snowflake/connector/connection.py#L131